# Why do I get a 404 error when trying to deploy a copy of Watson's Concept Insight demo?

Tags: ibm-watson

I have forked Watson's new Concept Insight demo from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/concept-insights-nodejs and added my credentials for the Concept Insight service.   I don't get any errors when I run it, but all I get when I browse to localhost:3000 is this JSON object:

```
{"code":404,"error":"Not Found"}
```

It obviously is finding the application but the application is not finding something somewhere.  Is there anything else that I need to customize in order to run this demo?

Thanks, David

Answer (score 1):

I added the `index.html` that was missing. Next time, feel free to open an issue in the repository.

see: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/concept-insights-nodejs/issues/3

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  The code on Github is missing the index.html file.  Somebody should fix that.